# Decide a parameterization for a parametric curve at a specific point

Tags: analysis

I have an equation like this:
$$r(t)=\langle t\sin(t), t\cos(t), 6t\rangle$$
that I want to solve the parameterization of in the point $(\sin(3), 3\cos(3), -2)$.

What I have tried so far is to identify that the parameter value is $t=-2$. So I solve it for

$$r = r(-2)+tr'(-2)$$

Witch should give me the parameterization. This is the only way I can see it making sense, but the exercise template say it is wrong. Have I misunderstood something?

Comment: $$ \begin{align} \text{before:} & \quad r(t)= < t sin(t), t cos(t), 6t > \\ \\ \text{after:} & \quad r(t)=\langle t\sin(t), t\cos(t), 6t\rangle \end{align} $$ Note $\sin$ and $\cos$, coded as \sin and \cos. The backslash not only de-italicizes, but also results in propser spacing between $t$ and $\sin$ in $t\sin(t)$ or in $t\sin t.$ I mention both of those latter examples to show that context-dependent nature of the spacing. Note also \langle and \rangle.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Sorry, long time since using the latex syntax.

Comment: @Nosrati Could you maybe elaborate? Do not really understand what you did there

Comment: $$\dfrac{t\sin(t)}{t\cos(t)}=\dfrac{\sin(3)}{3\cos(3)}$$
$$\tan t=\dfrac13\tan3$$
also $6t=-2$ then $t=-\dfrac13$
we should have
$$\tan-\dfrac13=\dfrac13\tan3$$
is this true?

Comment: Ahh yes now I get it. And yes it is!